# ng-routed AngularJS SPA ng-show a Bootstrap Carousel not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, ngroute

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/frllqX)**

I'm developing an AngularJS SPA, using ng-route and ng-animate. I'm trying to display the Bootstrap Carousel on the `index.html#/` using ng-show. Very simple task.

I want the Carousel to show on the index page, but not on the about page or the contact page.

I'm trying to do the logic in my `indexController` like so:

```
  if ($location.path() == "/") {
      $scope.isIndexPage = true;
  }
```

And in my HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" ng-show="isIndexPage">
```

But it does not work as expected: the Carousel does not display. Once the `ng-show` attribute is removed, the carousel displays, but on all pages.

How can I get the Carousel to display only on the index page? I've tried variations such as `ng-include`-ing and `ng-if`ing `carousel.htm`. Numerous Google searches such as "AngularJS SPA and Bootstrap Carousel" reveal unanswered SO questions.

Thanks in advance for any input. Here's the [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/frllqX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strange not to put something that is specific to the home page into the template of the home page, but anyway... 
Your code has 2 main problems:

1. you're trying to access a variable from the indexController scope from a part of the page that is not controlled by this controller. The controller only controls its view. The $scope of the controller is limited to its view.
2. You're initializing the isIndexPage variable only once. It never changes after.

Solution:

- create a controller for the whole body of the page, and put the logic used to control the visibility of the carousel in that controller
- use a function that will return true or false based on the current location

See http://plnkr.co/edit/8luxeIbyIPEKy0LkemM0?p=preview for a fork of your plunker (the additional JS code is at the end of script.js):

```
appname.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.isIndexPage = function() {
    return $location.path() === '/';
  }
});
```

and in the index.html file:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-show="isIndexPage()" ...>
```

Comment: I've deployed it to my main application and it worked! Thank you thank you thank you! I'll watch out for those controller scope shenanigans from now.